# How to find the MVUE for the Var$(x_i)$ of a Geometric Distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

Suppose that $X_1, \ldots ,X_n$ form a random sample from a geometric distribution with parameter $0<\theta<1$ whose PMF is $p(x) = θ(1−θ)^x$,for $x \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.
It is known that this distribution has mean $E[X_i]=\frac{1−\theta}{\theta}$ and variance Var$(X_i) = \frac{1−\theta}{\theta^2}$, for $i \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.

I found that $Y:=\sum x$ is the complete and sufficient statistic for $\theta$ and that the MLE for $\theta=\frac{n}{Y+n}$.

I need to find the unique MVUE for Var$(x)$.
so far I have that unbiased estimator for $\frac{1}{\theta}=\frac{Y+n}{n}$.

Comment: Can you find unbiased estimators of $1/\theta$ and $1/\theta^2$ based on $Y$? [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for typesetting math.

Comment: Is the unbiased estimator for $1/\theta=(Y+n)/n$? I don't know how to get the unbiased estimator for $1/\theta^2$.

Comment: Use E(X^2)=Var(X)+[E(X)]^2.

Comment: Alright, I did this and got a weird answer for $E[X^2]$ but I'm not understanding how this fits back into solving for $E[1/\theta^2]$

Comment: You need to edit your post and add your attempts to get it reopened.

Comment: Is that good? I'm not sure what I need to fix the post.

Comment: I have voted to reopen. Basically show whatever you have tried (see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) thread on meta), even the 'weird' answer for $E[X^2]$.